# Underage Jewish King in Judaism

Tags: halacha-theory, malchut-royalty, parashas-shoftim

Parshas Shoftim deals with some Mitzvos for a Jewish King. IIRC, a son inherits his father king and can be appointed as such at any age<sup>1</sup> - Solomon, for example, was 12 and Yoash was 7 ("בֶּן-שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים יְהוֹאָשׁ בְּמָלְכוֹ").

That made me think of two problems,

1. as underage kids are exempt from Mitzvos, so would be an underage king - therefore one can gather gold and horses and women until he's 13.
2. one can have unlimited power, incl. declaring Mordim Bemalchut, killing them off, waging wars, setting taxes, taking slaves, making private roads, etc. His opinion may be easily swang by his counselors, wreaking havoc in the Jewish kingdom.

[How] does Judaism deal with the problem of underage kings?

<sup>1(a clear source is needed, but I didn't find any limitations)</sup>

Comment: He can't marry -women - he's underage!